# Angular HttpClient with HttpParams and Python Pyramid Back-End

Tags: angular, pyramid

I am writing a front-end application in Angular and have a back-end application written in the Pyramid Web Framework (python), but I'm having a number of issues passing request query parameters from the front-end to the back-end via `HttpClient` and `HttpParams`, e.g.:

```
const params = HttpParams().append('type', 'string1;string2');
return this.http.get(apiUrl, {params: params});
```

(where `this.http` is an instance of `HttpClient` for the service)

On the back-end, I have a view that matches the request, but the value for `request.params` in this case is:

```
NestedMultiDict([('type', 'string1'), ('string2', '')])
```

whereas, I would expect the value to be:

```
NestedMultiDict([('type', 'string1;string2')])
```

Am I using `HttpClient` + `HttpParams` correctly? Or is this just another example of the open Angular issue at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24754 ?

**EDIT**: The more I look, the more this looks like an Angular issue. jQuery encodes the query string as `type=string1%3Bstring2` while Angular sets it as `type=string1;string`. On the other hand, if I use:

```
const params = HttpParams().set('type', encodeURIComponent('string1;string2'));
```

Then, Angular sets the query string to `type=string1%253Bstring2` which pyramid then decodes in `request.params` as `NestedMultiDict([('type', 'string1%3Bstring2')])`. Calling `urllib.parse.unquote(request.params['type'])` then results in the value `string1;string2`. So, angular is properly encoding the '%' character present in the URI encoded string, but won't encode the ';' in the unencoded string...

Answer (score 1):

Use set method:

```
const params = HttpParams().set('type', 'string1;string2');
```

cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this seems to make no difference; the url (with query string) requested from the server did not change

Comment: that's the correct sintax, maybe u get the error on the backend?

Comment: I was using this syntax successfully until I needed to pass a string with ';' in it. The previous front-end was written in jQuery and the back-end would successfully parse all query strings passed to it